# stuck in python request json parse error: JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

When I run the python script to output a post request-response, I'm getting the following error

```
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting ',' delimiter]

 [{"pool": "https://my.pool-url.cc/pool?token=ewyhzxciOiJI", "headers": {"Connection": "close", "Content-Length": "666", "Accept-Encoding": "gzip", "Cf-Ipcountry": "US", "X-Forwarded-For": "1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8", "Cf-Ray": "4gwx2cfdqe43e2d3-QXR", "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http", "Cf-Visitor": "{"scheme":"http"}", "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.27.1", "Accept": "*/*", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Cf-Connecting-Ip": "1.1.1.1", "Cdn-Loop": "cloudflare"}, "time": "Wed Apr  6 23:17:29 2022", "regular_keys": [{"final_key": "5mw4ssn3fbg2hv1jbf6c7x8z9z0q:0q9zwv8ge7hr6t5yd4a3sf2d1f"}]}]
```

The error seems to be caused due to `"Cf-Visitor": "{` making the json format invalid.
I want to parse the JSON output and display the final_key after the colon

for example:

```
0q9zwv8ge7hr6t5yd4a3sf2d1f
```

I tried:

```
r.json()[0]['regular_keys'][0]['final_key']
```

Comment: can you paste your code? for example, which line of code outputs `[{"pool"...`?

Comment: The json is malformed. It seems like some quotes are not being escaped or an object was not properly stringified: `"{"scheme":"http"}"` It doesn't seem like the outer quotes should be here.

Comment: As @Mark said. Is the server returning this malformed json, in which case can you fix the server? If the http library is messing up the response, can you use a different http library? Worst case, you could patch the string to add the needed quoting before decoding it as json.

Comment: The server is most likely not using a JSON library to produce the response, and as a result it's making mistakes. It should be fixed to use a proper library.

Comment: If you can't fix the JSON (e.g. because the API is run by a third party) you will have to get the content of the response, fix it with `replace()` or regular expressions and parse it manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSON has a syntax error in it. [image: Screenshot of JSON code]

You may want to escape the ends of the strings using `\"`.